# Django import variables from file

Tags: python, django, variables, django-import-export

I want to create a new .py file where I want to store some specific variables that are going to change continuously

For example in a variables.py

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 10
var3 = "Hello"
```

And then in the views.py just do from **myapp**.variables import *
And I want to use them in all the views only rendering

```
{{ var1 }}
{{ var2 }}
```

Why it doesnt work ?

Comment: You need to send these in the context too.. One (not the best way) of doing it is sending `locals()` in the context

Comment: you have to pass them in as context. ie: `return render('index.html',{var1:var1,var2:var2,var3:var3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they aren't being used by the views, but only for the rendering you could make a context_processor

inside your_app/variables.py

```
def my_variables(request):
    return {
        "var1": True,
        "var2": "foo",
        "var3": 42,
    }
```

then in your settings.py set

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "your_app.variables.my_variables",
)
```

These variables will now be available in every template that you render.

Comment: What if instead of variables i want to do "Ifs" ?

Comment: You should be able to put whatever you want, though if you want some complicated logic in your templates you should look into writing some [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/] (custom template tags).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass them in as context:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.variables import var1, var2, var3

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"var1":var1, "var2":var2, "var3":var3})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/